# Uneven training and test accuracy of simple CNN

Tags: deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network, training-data

I am using keras to implement a simple network for binary classification. I have a dataset with 2 categories and I am trying to train my network using this data. I don't have a huge data set. Total number of images in both categories are around 500.

The network is as below:

```
    self.model = Sequential()

    self.model.add(Conv2D(128, (2, 2), padding='same', input_shape=dataset.X_train.shape[1:]))
    self.model.add(Activation('relu'))
    self.model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    self.model.add(Dropout(0.25))

    self.model.add(Conv2D(64, (2, 2), padding='same'))
    self.model.add(Activation('relu'))
    self.model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    self.model.add(Dropout(0.25))
```

SGD config:

```
sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
```

I am using binary_crossentropy

The model training and loss graph look as below:
[image: Model Accuracy]
[image: Model Loss]

I am just wondering why there are a lot of big peaks in the graphs and what i can do to optimize it.

I am a newbie thus any comments and suggestions will be appreciated.

thanks!

Comment: That's why it's called **stochastic** gradient descent. By taking a minibatch instead of whole dataset in each iteration, the gradient is just a noisy estimation of the true gradient. Hence the error graph behaves a bit like random walk. As long as there are no major numerical instability, there's no need to optimize it.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the end of each epoch in the training/test,it seems that the accuracy drops(loss also increases),which means that the sequence of your dataset doesn't changes,this might not lead to better generalization of a the model,in my opinion,what you should do at each epoch is to randomize your dataset(batch) in the training phase,but for testing phase,you can just leave it since the model isn't doing any learning anymore

Comment: Thanks for your comment. You are right the accuracy drops at the end. However, I am using flow() method of keras `self.model.fit_generator(datagen.flow(dataset.X_train, dataset.Y_train,
                                                  batch_size=batch_size),
                                     samples_per_epoch=dataset.X_train.shape[0],
                                     nb_epoch=nb_epoch,
                                     validation_data=(dataset.X_valid, dataset.Y_valid))`. It should randomize the dataset by using random batch from the given dataset.

Comment: sorry,i dont know about keras,but if you are randomizing already,then it might be the nature of the dataset.Good luck

Answer (score 1):

I believe these peaks actually coincides with a start of new epoch. Throughout one epoch gradients of previous batches are used to compute the current gradient when you use momentum. This explains why loss is decreasing steadily throughout one epoch and hikes at the beginning of the next one, that is, when the new epoch starts optimiser doesn't use gradients computed for batches in previous epochs.